# Gamma function in complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, self-learning, gamma-function

Prove that
$$
\Gamma\left(z\right)
=
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{n}t^{z - 1}\left(1 - {t \over n}\right)^{n}\,{\rm d}t
\quad\mbox{for}\quad \Re z \gt 0
$$

---

I know that
$$
{\rm e}^{-t/n}
=
1 - {t \over n} + {t^{2} \over 2!\,n^{2}} - {t^{3} \over 3!\,n^{3}} + \cdots
$$

Then,
$$
0 \leq {\rm e}^{-t/n} - \left(1 - {t \over n}\right) \leq {t^{2} \over 2n^{2}}
$$

After there, I cannot do this. Please continue to prove. Thank you for helping.

Comment: What theorems do you know what switching limits and integrals?

Comment: Do you already know that for $\operatorname{Re} z > 0$ you have $\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}\,dt$? Then dominated convergence would be a good way.

Comment: Yes. That's, I need to show that $\int_{0}^{n}t^{z-1}(1-t/n)^n dt-\int_{0}^{n} t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt\lt \epsilon$ Right? Well, how? @DanielFischer

Comment: Let $$\varphi_n(t) = \begin{cases}(1-t/n)^n &, 0 \leqslant t \leqslant n\\ 0 &, t > n. \end{cases}$$ Then show that $e^{-t}$ dominates the $\varphi_n$.

Comment: In fact, I have its answer. $$e^{-t}-(1-t/n)^n\le e. \frac{e^{-t}t^2}{2n}$$ But, I cannot see how to write right hand side of the inequality. Can you explain a bit? @DanielFischer

Comment: For the dominated convergence theorem, you only need $0 \leqslant \varphi_n(t) \leqslant e^{-t}$, and the pointwise convergence. If you can't use the dominated convergence theorem, it becomes more messy, _then_ you need estimates of the difference.

Comment: So if I understand the OP's thought "correctly" then I would need to show the right inequality to be true. So let x = t/n, then 0 < x < 1. Then the inequality is:
f(x) = e^(-x) - 1 + x - 0.5x^2 < 0 for 0 < x < 1. We have f'(x) = -e^(-x) + 1 - x, and f''(x) = -1 + e^(-x) < 0, so f'(x) < f'(0) = 0, and so f(x) < f(0) = 0. So the RHS is verified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{n}t^{z - 1}\pars{1 - {t \over n}}^{n}\,\dd t
=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n^{z}\int_{0}^{1}t^{z - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{n}\,\dd t}
=\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n^{z}\,{\rm B}\pars{z,n + 1}}
\\[3mm]&=\lim_{n \to \infty}
\bracks{n^{z}\,{\Gamma\pars{z}\,\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{z + n + 1}}}
=\Gamma\pars{z}\,\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n^{z}\,
{\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{z + n + 1}}}
\\[3mm]&=\Gamma\pars{z}\,\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n^{z}\,
{\pars{n + 1}^{n + 1/2}\expo{-\pars{n + 1}}\root{2\pi}
 \over
 \pars{z + n + 1}^{z + n + 1/2}\expo{-\pars{z + n + 1}}\root{2\pi}}}
\\[3mm]&=\Gamma\pars{z}\,\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
\pars{n \over n + z + 1}^{z}\pars{n + 1\over n + z + 1}^{n + 1/2}\expo{z}}
=\Gamma\pars{z}\expo{z}\lim_{n \to \infty}
\pars{1 + {z \over n + 1}}^{-n - 1/2}
\\[3mm]&=\Gamma\pars{z}\expo{z}\,
\underbrace{\lim_{n \to \infty}
\exp\pars{-\bracks{n + \half}\ln\pars{1 + {z \over n + 1}}}}
_{\ds{\expo{-z}}}
\end{align}
where ${\rm B}$ is the $\it Beta$ function. We used the
identity $\ds{{\rm B}\pars{x,y} = \int_{0}^{1}t^{x - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{y - 1}\,\dd t}$ and the property
$\ds{{\rm B}\pars{x,y} = {\Gamma\pars{x}\Gamma\pars{y} \over \Gamma\pars{x + y}}}$.
The final limit is performed by using the Stirling's asymptotic behavior of the Gamma function.

> Then
>   $$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
> \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{n}t^{z - 1}\pars{1 - {t \over n}}^{n}\,\dd t
> =
> \Gamma\pars{z}}
> $$

Answer (score 1):

Let be $$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}\operatorname{e}^{-t}\operatorname{d}t\quad\text{for}\; \Re(z)>0.\tag 1$$
Prove that
$$
\Gamma(z)=
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{n}t^{z - 1}\left(1 - {t \over n}\right)^{n}\operatorname{d}t
\quad\mbox{for}\;\Re(z) > 0.\tag 2
$$

We have to prove that 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}\operatorname{e}^{-t}\operatorname{d}t-\int_{0}^{n}t^{z-1}\left(1 - {t \over n}\right)^{n}\operatorname{d}t\right]=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\int_{0}^{n}\left\{\operatorname{e}^{-t}-\left(1 - {t \over n}\right)^{n}\right\}t^{z-1}\operatorname{d}t+\int_n^\infty \operatorname{e}^{-t}t^{z-1}\operatorname{d}t\right]
$$
converges to $0$.

From the convergence of the integral on the right in (1) it follows that 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_n^\infty t^{z-1}\operatorname{e}^{-t}\operatorname{d}t=0
$$

Hence we have to prove that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{n}\left\{\operatorname{e}^{-t}-\left(1 - {t \over n}\right)^{n}\right\}t^{z-1}\operatorname{d}t=0
$$

Observe that, when $0\le y< 1$, comparing the series $\operatorname{e}^{y}=1+y+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{y^k}{k!}$ and $\frac{1}{1-y}=1+y+\sum_{k=2}^\infty y^k$ it follows
$$
1+y\le \operatorname{e}^{y}\le \frac{1}{1-y}.
$$
Writing $t/n$ for $y$ one has
$$
\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^{-n}\ge \operatorname{e}^{-t} \ge \left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^{n}
$$
and so 
$$ 
0\le \operatorname{e}^{-t} - \left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^{n} =\operatorname{e}^{-t}\left[1 - \operatorname{e}^{t}\left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^{n}\right] \le \operatorname{e}^{-t}\left[1 - \left(1-\frac{t^2}{n^2}\right)^{n}\right]\tag 3 
$$
where we used $\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^{n}\le \operatorname{e}^{t}$ in the last inequality.

Now, if $0\le\alpha\le 1$, $(1-\alpha)^n\ge 1-n\alpha$ by induction when $n\alpha<1$ and obviously when $n\alpha\ge 1$; and, writing $t^2/n^2$ for $\alpha$, we get 
$$
1 - \left(1-\frac{t^2}{n^2}\right)^{n}\le \frac{t^2}{n^2}\tag 4
$$
and so from (3) and (4)
$$
0\le \operatorname{e}^{-t}-\left(1 - {t \over n}\right)^{n}\le \operatorname{e}^{-t}\frac{t^2}{n}\tag 5
$$
By the inequalities (5) and by te fact that $|t^z|=t^x$ (where $x$ is the real part of $z$), it follows
$$
\left|\int_{0}^{n}\left\{\operatorname{e}^{-t}-\left(1 - {t \over n}\right)^{n}\right\}t^{z-1}\operatorname{d}t\right|\le \int_{0}^{n}\operatorname{e}^{-t}\frac{t^2}{n}t^{x-1}\operatorname{d}t\le \frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{n}\operatorname{e}^{-t}t^{x+1}\operatorname{d}t.
$$
Now $\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{e}^{-t}t^{x+1}\operatorname{d}t$ converges, so $\int_{0}^{n}\operatorname{e}^{-t}t^{x+1}\operatorname{d}t$ is bounded.

Therefore we may conclude that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{n}\left\{\operatorname{e}^{-t}-\left(1 - {t \over n}\right)^{n}\right\}t^{z-1}\operatorname{d}t=0
$$